# .Net Framework Data Provider error Fluent Nhibernate for Informix DataBase

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, autofac, informix

I try to configure Fluent Nhibernate with AutoFac and Informix DataBase, but an error is showwing for me:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Factory Nhibernate

```
    ISessionFactory factory = Fluently.Configure()
                                 .Database(
                       IfxSQLIConfiguration
                      .Informix1000
                      .Provider<NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider>()
                      .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.IfxDriver>()
                      .Dialect<NHibernate.Dialect.InformixDialect>()
                      .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(databaseKey))
                      .ShowSql())
                      .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TvLoginMapping>()
                      .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomTypeConvention>()
                      )
                      .BuildSessionFactory();
                factories.Add(databaseKey, factory);
```

WebConfig File:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="INFORMIX" connectionString=" Provider=Ifxoledbc.2;Password=*******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Data Source=******;Database=*****;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was used a wrong confinguration to use Informix and OleDbDriver

```
          ISessionFactory factory = Fluently.Configure()
                                 .Database(
                       IfxSQLIConfiguration
                      .Informix1000
                      .ConnectionString("conectionString")
                      .Driver<OleDbDriver>()
                      .Dialect<InformixDialect1000>()
                        //.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(databaseKey))

                      .ShowSql())
                      .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TvLoginMapping>()
                      .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomTypeConvention>()
                      )
                      .BuildSessionFactory();
                    factories.Add(databaseKey, factory);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do a `<clear/>` before you add your entry.

You can check machine.config to see if you have any other Informix's in there.

I don't think the Dialect's are "universal" for all versions of your library.

See:
https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/NHibernate/3.0.0.GA/Release/All/NHibernate/NHibernate/Dialect/InformixDialect.cs

Note the comments of the class:

```
/// Summary description for InformixDialect.
/// This dialect is intended to work with IDS version 7.31
/// However I can test only version 10.00 as I have only this version at work
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The InformixDialect defaults the following configuration properties:
/// <list type="table">
///     <listheader>
///         <term>ConnectionDriver</term>
///         <description>NHibernate.Driver.OdbcDriver</description>
///         <term>PrepareSql</term>
///         <description>true</description>
///     </listheader>
///     <item>
///         <term>connection.driver_class</term>
///         <description><see cref="NHibernate.Driver.OdbcDriver" /></description>
///     </i
```

I don't have an "Informix" version eye.  So this is just a hint I guess.

Also note there are these dialects:

https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/NHibernate/3.0.0.GA/Release/All/NHibernate/NHibernate/Dialect/InformixDialect0940.cs?ImageName=NHibernate

https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/NHibernate/3.0.0.GA/Release/All/NHibernate/NHibernate/Dialect/InformixDialect1000.cs?ImageName=NHibernate

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is one of the alternate for NHibernate; 
and it is supported with Informix.
Unfortunately Informix native .net driver has no LINQ support.
You may have to use DB2 Entity Framework driver to connect IDS server.
For DB2 Entity Framework driver to connect IDS server you have to enable DRDA protocol with IDS server.